# Printing not working with UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm using `UIDocumentInteractionController` to view a PDF.  When I open a PDF, click the square with the arrow pointing up in the top right corner and select print nothing happens.  Any idea how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:path];
interactionController.delegate = self;
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [interactionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
});
```

### Update:

I forgot to mention, I also have the below code because without it the status bar shows up over the document preview menu bar.  I had to add the below code because my app always has the status bar hidden and without it when the document preview opens the status bar covers the menu bar.  If I remove the code the print functionality works fine...

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller
{
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelStatusBar];

    return [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController;
```

And these to your .m file:

```
self.documentInteractionController= [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];

//set delegate

[self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

//provide button's frame from where popover will be lauched

[self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

For Ref:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15664394/5184217

Comment: I tried that code and it didn't fix the issue but I found out some more details.  I added some more code and an update.  Thanks for the help!